# how to pass self(this) to addEventListener without breaking removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding checkboxchange event to checkbox here. (moveButton is a checkBox because im using CSS checkbox hack)

```
var self = this;
this.moveButton.addEventListener("change", function(e){self.toggleMove(e, self)});
```

if the checkbox is checked it adds an eventListener to body.document

```
DR.prototype.toggleMove = function(e, self){
    if(self.moveButton.checked){
        document.body.addEventListener("click", function bodyEvent(e){self.removeableEventHandler(e, self)}, false);
    }else{
        console.log("unchecked");
        document.body.removeEventListener("click",  function bodyEvent(e){self.removeableEventHandler(e, self)}, false);
    }
}
```

if i don't wrap self.removeableEventHandler in a function i am unable to attach self to the function, but when i wrap it in a function i will be unable to remove the event when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
DR.prototype.removeableEventHandler = function(e, self){
            console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            self.ele.style.top = e.clientY + "px"; 
            self.ele.style.left = e.clientX + "px"; 
};
```

So it seems to be like I'm having a bit of a scope conundrum here. Not sure how to fix it. I'm trying to make a form moveable when the checkbox is checked and then removing the move event when the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeEventListener` works by passing the original function reference. If you pass a copy it wont work.

You can do:

```
DR.prototype.toggleMove = (function () {
    var boundBodyEvent;
    function bodyEvent(e) {
        this.removeableEventHandler(e);
    }
    return function (e) {
        if (this.moveButton.checked) {
            boundBodyEvent= bodyEvent.bind(this);
            document.body.addEventListener("click", boundBodyEvent, false);
        } else {
            document.body.removeEventListener("click", boundBodyEvent, false);
        }
    };
}());
```

I don't think you need to pass `self` around, that seems strange to me. I'm using `bind` to override the `this` in `bodyEvent` to refernce your `DR` instance instead of the DOM Element.

I'm also using immediate invocation to avoid having to put the `bodyEvent` in the global scope.

---

Alternatively, you could also not bother removing the event listener and have a switch inside the event listener:

```
DR.prototype.init = function () {
    var self = this;
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (self.moveButton.checked) {
            self.removeableEventHandler(e);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Halcyon filled another hole in my knowledge base. :)

Answer (score 1):

removeEventListener callbak function need to be reference to the same function as in addEventListener, try this:

```
function bodyEvent(e) {
    self.removeableEventHandler(e, self);
}
DR.prototype.toggleMove = function(e, self) {
    if (self.moveButton.checked) {
        document.body.addEventListener("click", bodyEvent, false);
    } else {
        console.log("unchecked");
        document.body.removeEventListener("click", bodyEvent, false);
    }
};
```

Comment: I thought this worked but I don't think it does. `self` in `bodyEvent` is unbound.